# How to remove docker storage on Mac

Tags: macos, docker

I have used

```
docker image rm -f
```

on all docker images. This does *nothing* for disk space usage on mac.

The following bug talks about it: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371

So what do I do? Should i delete the storage file directly?

```
 $HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2
```

Comment: Have you tried the `prune` commands that were introduced in 1.13? E.g., `docker image prune`, `docker system prune`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have intermediate image layers pending to be deleted. Try this:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
```

Comment: Y thanks I did that - but your answer is useful for people reading this question so I will upvote.

Comment: Thanks for that. If you can't free space doing that, maybe your problem is not on docker because all of this is working for me.